# iterate through all enum variants of a given enum

Tags: c++, enums

Is it possible to iterate through all enum variants of a given enum. I have an `std::unordered_map<Enum, Value_Type>` with enum variant as key. I need to check whether all the enum variants of a given enum exist as key in `std::unordered_map<Enum, Value_Type>`.

Comment: What means “enum variants”? Enumerators?

Comment: If you know the pattern your enum values have then yes, you can utilize it to iterate through them. The language itself doesn't have the means to iterate through the enums.

Answer (score 0):

Consider making a helper method like `AllKeyPresent` illustrated in a sample program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
//declare an enum
enum DIR : int {NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST}; 

/**
 * AllKeysPresent: return true if and only if map contains all enum keys
 */
template<typename T = int> 
bool AllKeysPresent(const std::unordered_map<DIR, T>& myMap)
{
    bool allKeysPresent = true;
    //loop over enum, starting with the first entry up and including the last entry
    for (int key = DIR::NORTH; key <= DIR::EAST; key++)
    {
        if (myMap.find(static_cast<DIR>(key)) == myMap.end())
        {
            allKeysPresent = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //TODO: check if at least one valid key is present. return false if the map is empty
    return allKeysPresent;
}

int main()
{
    //make a map with all keys
    std::unordered_map<DIR, int> mapWithAllKeys = { {DIR::NORTH, -1}, {DIR::SOUTH, -2}, {DIR::WEST, -3}, {DIR::EAST, -4} };
    std::unordered_map<DIR, int> mapWithSomeKeys = { {DIR::NORTH, -1}, {DIR::SOUTH, -2} };
    std::cout << AllKeysPresent(mapWithAllKeys) << std::endl;
    std::cout << AllKeysPresent(mapWithSomeKeys) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would also recommend declaring your enum like this
`enum DIR : int {DIR_FIRST, NORTH, SOUTH, WEST, EAST, DIR_LAST};`
where DIR_FIRST and DIR_LAST are just dummy entries, and change for loop iteration to `for (int key = DIR::DIR_FIRST + 1; key < DIR:DIR_LAST; key++)`. This way, if someone decides to add a new entry to your enum like `SOUTHWEST`, then `AllKeysPresent` will still work